# How to use VBA to loop through cutting a range of cells and pasting into next row

Tags: excel, vba

The purpose of this VBA is to make a single long row of values (tens of thousands) into something more readable by keeping each row limited to 22 values. I have a manual version of this which works for 200 rows, but am hoping to use looping to save myself time and hopefully improve performance.

Example:
I have values in A1:ZZ1 and am trying to cut W1:ZZ1 and paste into A2, then cut W2:ZD2 and paste into A3 until there are no values left to cut and paste.

I'm using Excel 2010.

```
Sub InsertScript22perLine()
'Turn off screen updating to speed up macro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("W1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("W2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'Turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub InsertScript22perLine()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Starting column for input data
    Dim sStartCol As String
    Dim lStartCol As Long

    ' Count of columns
    Dim lColCount As Long

    ' Count of columns of data for output
    Dim lRowLen As Long
    lRowLen = 22

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = 2

    sStartCol = "W"
    lStartCol = Range(sStartCol & 1).Column

    ' Get the column count
    lColCount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For a = lStartCol To lColCount Step lRowLen
        Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(lRow, lRowLen)).Value = Range(Cells(1, a), Cells(1, a + lRowLen)).Value
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This does everything except for deleting the contents in W1 to the last column, but performing this delete manually is easy enough. Thank you for your help!